# lazy-imports-mixin - Error: No imports found in the specified group

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Experimenting with Polymer 2 and using the sample app from polymer cli, I replaced the `Polymer.importHref` with the lazy import mixin. However, it complains `Error: No imports found in the specified group.`.

It looks pretty cut and dry, but am I doing something wrong?

```
   <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/lazy-imports/lazy-imports-
    mixin.html">

   <link rel="lazy-import" group="lazy" href="foo-element.html">
```

---

```
  <script>
    class MyApp extends Polymer.LazyImportsMixin(Polymer.Element) {
      static get is() { return 'my-app'; }

      static get properties() {
        return {
          page: {
            type: String,
            reflectToAttribute: true,
            observer: '_pageChanged',
          },
          routeData: Object,
          subroute: String,
          // This shouldn't be neccessary, but the Analyzer isn't picking up
          // Polymer.Element#rootPath
          rootPath: String,
        };
      }

      static get observers() {
        return [
          '_routePageChanged(routeData.page)',
        ];
      }

      _routePageChanged(page) {
        // If no page was found in the route data, page will be an empty string.
        // Default to 'view1' in that case.
        this.page = page || 'fooElement';

        // Close a non-persistent drawer when the page & route are changed.
        if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
          this.$.drawer.close();
        }
      }

      _pageChanged(page) {
        this.importLazyGroup('lazy').then((results) => {
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lazy import group should be after `dom-module` but before `template`. Something like :

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <link rel="lazy-import" group="lazy" href="foo-element.html">
  <template>
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this if correct, but I use polymer 2.0's sample app from polymer cli and it comes with lazy imports by default. Try deleting the import of lazy-imports-mixin and the group attribute on the lazy-import link tag.

```
<!-- <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/lazy-imports/lazy-imports-
    mixin.html">
 -->
   <link rel="lazy-import" href="foo-element.html">
```

Comment: No, that is incorrect.  I am speaking of using the Mixin. You are referring to you the js api

Comment: What there are in `foo-element.html` ? also `<link rel="lazy-import" group="lazy" href="foo-element.html">` line should be placed after `<dom-module id="my-app">` but before `<template>`